# Как запретить выполнение функций дважды для текущего пользователя?

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть функция подсчета просмотров

```
    if( current_user_can('author') || current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') ){  
    function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, 'post_count', true);
    $count++;
    update_post_meta($postID, 'post_count', $count);
    echo $count.;
}
```

которую я использую в файле single.php

Но она она работает каждый раз когда обновляется страница что может вызвать накрутку пользователем
И что бы этого избежать
функция должна выполнялась только один раз для одного зарегистрированного пользователя на одной странице.
при повторной попытке нечего бы не происходило бы.
Если зайдет другой пользователь то функция выполнится для него но только 1 раз 
и так далее для всех других пользователей.
Необходимо, чтобы проверка повторялась на каждой странице отдельно. 
И не переходил на другие страницы в single.php

Кто нибудь знает как это сделать?

Comment: Для сохранения состояния в РНР используются куки и сессии

Comment: @Ипатьев мне необходимо что бы результат хранился на аккаунте постоянно. на случай если он попробует зайти с другого браузера

Comment: Такие детали надо писать в тексте вопроса. Ну заведи тогда таблицу просмотров постов пользователями.

Comment: @Ипатьев а как мне это сделать?

Comment: создай таблицу post_counts с полями idpost iduser, и пиши туда просмотры

Comment: @Ипатьев ты имеешь в веду добавление таблиц в базу данных?

Comment: не таблиц, а таблицЫ

Comment: @Ипатьев  Ну таблицу я создал http://static2.keep4u.ru/2018/11/29/jhjh5a2e5c433f21eb77.jpg А что дальше делать если единственное что я могу это либо создать точно такую же функцию как и с просмотрами которая просто будет добавлять значение в бд без остановки или создать функцию но уже запретить повтор на всех страницах вордпрес

Comment: @zeni1agent Посмотри на то, что ты создал, ставиш простую проверку, если пользыватель не просматривал даный пост, делаеш счетчик +1, записываеш ID пользывателя и post ID в созданную тобой таблицу, если просматривал(соответсвие найдено в таблице пользыватель ID, post ID) ничего не далеш.